# Method analogues for binding attributes in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to use my EF Core classes as views in my controller. So, I don't want to use binding attributes in my EFC classes, but want to make new classes, which are inherited from EFC classes. So, is it possible to mark properties in inherited view class as "non-binding" or "binding-required".

Let's look at sample:

```
public class EFModelClass
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public int A { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
public class EFInheritedView : EFModelClass
{
    public EFInheritedView()
    {
        SetBindingValue(Id, BindNever);
        SetBindingValue(A, BindRequired);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public void Index([FromBody]EFInheritedView view)
    {
         //Do something
    }
}
```

Here, as you could see, `SetBindingValue` is a method/code part I'm looking for.

Comment: Don't do it. Keep your views and entity models as far apart as possible. In the long run, it's far better. You can use something like `AutoMapper` to map between the two to make things easier.

Comment: @DavidG So, It's not bad to clone EF model classes in view, is it?

Comment: Well aside from a CMS, views almost never match an entity directly anyway.

Comment: @DavidG Sometimes it looks like a good idea (as a Okkam blade rule). Now, I develop Web API service. I though that implementation like this could allow me to realize partial code representation, decrease code size and improve scalability... But, I'm newbie in ASP.NET...

Comment: Those are aspirational goals for sure, but all we're talking about are plain, simple classes that won't bloat your project at all. As for scalability, having secific view models is the preference there anyway.

Comment: @DavidG Hmm... Thank you for advice!